# pySpark toRowMatrix confusion

Tags: python, pyspark, cosine-similarity

I am attempting do use columnSimiliraties via pyspark and

```
import pyspark
pyspark.__version__
#'2.2.0'

from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix, IndexedRowMatrix

test = np.array[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]

# so I can compare rows with each other I need to transpose my data
test = np.transpose(test) 

# Calculate exact similarities
exactSim = mat.columnSimilarities()
print(exactSim.numRows(),exactSim.numCols())
# 4 4
```

As expected this gives me a 4 by 4 matrix

When I generate a rowMatrix from this I expect that this should preserve this shape

```
rowMat = exactSim.toRowMatrix()
print(rowMat.numRows(), rowMat.numCols())
# 3 4
```

So somehow I am losing rows on this conversion.

I believe that it is the last row which is all zeros - but ideally i would like all rows outputted...any ideas how i can get the square matrix?

Answer (score 0):

From the answer to your previous question [Problems with pySpark Columnsimilarities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543388/problems-with-pyspark-columnsimilarities/45550039#45550039),

> [T]he columnSimilarities method only returns the off diagonal
>   entries of the upper triangular portion of the similarity matrix. With
>   the absence of the 1's along the diagonal, you may have 0's for entire
>   rows in the resulting similarity matrix.

Indeed in this example, the underlying RDD of matrix entries your resulting matrix is the following:

```
>>> exactSim.entries.collect()

[MatrixEntry(0, 1, 1.0), MatrixEntry(0, 2, 1.0), 
 MatrixEntry(0, 3, 1.0), MatrixEntry(1, 2, 1.0), 
 MatrixEntry(1, 3, 1.0), MatrixEntry(2, 3, 1.0)]
```

This is a sparse representation of the underlying matrix, meaning none of the zero value entries are included. So, viewing this as a dense matrix, we actually have:

```
[[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

PySpark stores the columnSimilarities in the most efficient way. This is  because, mathematically speaking, the underlying matrix is a symmetric matrix and the diagonal entries will always be 1.0 regardless of your input. So, all that is necessary to compute and store is the off diagonal upper triangular portion.

With this in mind, it is fairly straight forward to return the full similarity matrix. We do this by combining the upper triangular entries with the transpose of the upper triangular entries (the lower triangular entries) and the diagonal entries.

```
entryRDD=exactSim.entries\
          .union(exactSim.transpose().entries)\
          .union(sc.parallelize([(i,i,1.0) for i in range(exactSim.numCols())]))

rowMat=CoordinateMatrix(entryRDD).toRowMatrix()
```

yielding the desired full similarity matrix as a PySpark RowMatrix.

Comment: can you please interpret the result of the maxtrix entry like how do I know which ones were compared given that i and j are the columns. I mean which data from var test are being compared.