# Pyspark columnSimilarities() usage for calculation of cosine similarities between products

Tags: pyspark, cosine-similarity

I have a big dataset and need to calculate cosine similarities between products in the context of item-item collaborative filtering for product recommendations. As the data contains more than 50000 items and 25000 rows, I opted for using Spark and found the function `columnSimilarities()` which can be used on DistributedMatrix, specifically on a `RowMatrix` or `IndexedRowMatrix`.

But, there is 2 issues I'm wondering about.

1) In the documentation, it's mentioned that:

> A RowMatrix is backed by an RDD of its rows, where each row is a local
>   vector. Since each row is represented by a local vector, the number of
>   columns is limited by the integer range but it should be much smaller
>   in practice.

As I have many products it seems that `RowMatrix` is not the best choice for building the similarity Matrix from my input which is a `Spark Dataframe`. That's why I decided to start by converting the dataframe to a `CoordinateMatrix` and then use `toRowMatrix()` because `columnSimilarities()` requires input parameter as RowMatrix. Meanwhile, I'm not sure of its performance..

2) I found out that:

> the columnSimilarities method only returns the off diagonal entries of
>   the upper triangular portion of the similarity matrix.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45550039/6837132)

Does this mean I cannot get the similarity vectors of all the products?

Comment: You should probably NOT compute all the pairwise similarities. Instead you should opt for an approximate nearest neighbors search instead.

Comment: What's the advantage of using nearest neighbors search instead? isn't it the same thing that I want to do? I mean it will calculate similarities and get the top K similar.

Answer (score 1):

So your current strategy is to compute the similarity between each item, i, and each other item. This means at best you have to compute the upper triangular of the distance matrix, I think that's (i^2 / 2) - i calculations. Then you have to sort for each of those i items.

If you are willing to trade off a little accuracy for runtime you can use approximate nearest neighbors (ANN). You might not find exactly the top NNS for an item but you will find very similar items and it will be orders of magnitude faster. No one dealing with moderately sized datasets calculates (or has the time to wait to calculate) the full set of distances.

Each ANN search method creates an index that will only generate a small set of candidates and compute distances within that subset (this is the fast part). The way the index is constructed provides different guarantees about the accuracy of the NN retrieval (this is the approximate part).

There are various ANN search libraries out there, annoy, nmslib, LSH. An accessible introduction is here: https://erikbern.com/2015/10/01/nearest-neighbors-and-vector-models-part-2-how-to-search-in-high-dimensional-spaces.html

HTH. Tim